# Cannot read property 'style' of null React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to react when I add a component for side bar with the following code I got the error:

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/sidebar.css";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  state = {};

  openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }

  closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a
            href="javascript:void(0)"
            class="closebtn"
            onclick={this.closeNav()}
          >
            &times;
          </a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
          <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
          <p>
            Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and
            push this content to the right.
          </p>
          <span
            styles={{ fontSize: "30", cursor: "pointer" }}
            onclick={this.openNav()}
          >
            &#9776; open
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Is the error in the part below?

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
```

What is the problem?

If any one can help it will very much appreciable.

Comment: You are trying to write JS into JSX? I dont think that is possible

Comment: React has a virtual DOM. So, your code probably will not work (in intended way). Also, You can handle this pretty simply in react by adding and removing a class based on particular component state, right?

Comment: the way you are using is not React way. you should store style value into state and show that in your elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the document element cannot be accessed until your DOM is fully loaded so you need to add a check if the element has been loaded or not:

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  //Here you are not binding your methods nor you are using the ES6 Arrow function so you need to change the code here also.
  openNav = () => {
    if (
      document.getElementById("mySidenav") &&
      document.getElementById("main")
    ) {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }
  };

  closeNav = () => {
    if (
      document.getElementById("mySidenav") &&
      document.getElementById("main")
    ) {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
           //Here you are calling the function on initial render that is why you are getting the error. you need to pass the function like this in order to trigger it on an event.
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick={this.closeNav}>
            &times;
          </a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
          <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
          <p>
            Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and
            push this content to the right.
          </p>
          <span
            styles={{ fontSize: "30", cursor: "pointer" }}
            //Same as above here also
            onclick={this.openNav}
          >
            &#9776; open
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The corrected component will be this.
You should see some concept over ES6 and Classes.

Comment: how can i covert the html code specified in "w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav" to a react component. i did what you suggested but the sidebar is not coming when i clicking the open butten that i didnot understand!

Comment: Got the solution?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use an anti-pattern from vanilla JS environment to get the link on DOM Node. See React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for usage of refs.

Since React has own DOM navigation environment, you should use only it. Update your code like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/sidebar.css";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state = {}

      this.mySidenav = React.createRef()
      this.main = React.createRef()
  }

  openNav() {
    this.mySidenav.current.style.width = "250px";
    this.main.current.style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }

  closeNav() {
    this.mySidenav.current.style.width = "0";
    this.main.current.style.marginLeft = "0";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="mySidenav" ref={this.mySidenav} class="sidenav">
          <a
            href="javascript:void(0)"
            class="closebtn"
            onclick={this.closeNav}
          >
            &times;
          </a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id="main" ref={this.main}>
          <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
          <p>
            Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.
          </p>
          <span
            styles={{ fontSize: "30", cursor: "pointer" }}
            onclick={this.openNav}
          >
            &#9776; open
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i covert the html code specified in "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav" to a react component

Comment: i did what you suggested but the sidebar is not coming when i clicking the open butten that i didnot understand!

Comment: When i did just like you said its showing error like "Cannot read property 'mySidenav' of undefined" on  this.mySidenav.current.style.width = "250px";

Answer (score 2):

document element cannot be accessed until your DOM is loaded so you need to  check if the element has been loaded or not

```
    if (
  document.getElementById("mySidenav") &&
  document.getElementById("main")
) {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

or use hook - useEffect()

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.getElementById("togBtn").style.cursor = "pointer";
   }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `onclick={this.openNav()}` you CALL a function instead of passing it to the prop.
It calls in the render phase, before component mounting, so your elements do not exist.
To fix it, you should pass a function instead. Simply do:

```
onclick={this.openNav}
onclick={this.closeNav}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `document.getElement...` seems an anti-pattern - see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for usage of `refs`

*Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.*

You may also want to keep track of widths within your `state` that way you can use `setState` to update the widths and have `style` properties within your JSX reflect those widths in the state.

Comment: how can i covert the html code specified in "w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav" to a react component

Answer (score 0):

Don't invoke the method directly, instead pass the method reference.

Try changing `onclick={this.openNav()}` to `onClick={this.openNav}`

and

`onclick={this.closeNav()}` to `onClick={this.closeNav}`

**Also** your JSX code is not right inside `render()` method. Try this:

```js
render() {
  return (

  <div>
    <div id="mySidenav" className="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="closebtn" onClick="{this.closeNav}">
        ×
      </a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
      <p>
        Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and
        push this content to the right.
      </p>
      <span style={{ fontsize: '30', cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick="{this.openNav}">
        &#9776; open
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: how can i covert the html code specified in "w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav" to a react component

Answer (score 0):

as my comment under your original post, you are not recommended to add styles that way. you should use state instead. For your question, it was your binding problem it should like this

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"
    class="closebtn"
    onclick={this.closeNav}
 >
```

and the same goes for your other element